# How do you pass the target element as an argument to an inline event handler?

Tags: javascript, events, target

Whew! First off, my apologies for the title, I don't speak English often.

My question is, using an inline event registration, how can I pass the target element as an argument? Like this:

```
<element onClick='someEvent(thisElement)'></element>
```

What I have tried:

```
<element onClick='someEvent(this)'></element>
```

The code above is not working. Please help... Thank's in advance!
I don't want to use addEventHandler 'coz the element will be created dynamically.

Comment: You forgot to post your source code.

Comment: @reporter: No, he just forgot to indent it. Fixed now.

Comment: [Using `this` should work fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/thai/sZpDe/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/mzxKc/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someEvent(t) {
    alert(t.tagName)
}
</script>

<a onclick='someEvent(this)'>Click me</a>
```

---

I think the cause of the problem is dynamic element generation. How are you adding the attribute to the element?

Why not just use `addEventHandler` during the dynamic element generation?

Comment: Waaaaaaah!!! Forgive me stackoverflow for being err! I thought it's not working coz I'm not getting the expected offsetTop... But why am I getting 4 as offsetTop of the element even if it's on the middle of the page? The element is inside a table, does it affect the offsetTop?

Comment: Yeah! :) Maybe I'll just mark your answer as correct since it made me look so stupid which I really am... Haha! Thanks anyway...